# Finding dyads with a same character string within specific sets of rows in R

Tags: r

I would like to know if, within a same Scan, my Dyadic individuals eat the same resources.

Here is what my data looks like right now:

| Individual | Scan | Food.Consumed | Dyad.ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Raisins | 1 |
| Aa | 1 | Melon | 1 |
| B | 1 | Raisins | 2 |
| Cc | 1 | Melon | 3 |
| Bb | 1 | Peach | 2 |
| Ee | 1 | Melon | 5 |
| E | 1 | Melon | 5 |
| F | 1 | Peach | 6 |
| Aa | 2 | Melon | 5 |
| C | 2 | Peach | 5 |
| A | 2 | Melon | 6 |

Each Dyad (A-Aa, B-Bb, etc...) has a specific ID number (Dyad.ID) to link the two individuals together.
Within a same Scan, the same individual is never mentioned twice. Sometimes, I have data for both individuals in a Dyad, and sometimes I do not (e.g In Scan = 1, the individual F has data collected but not Ff).

I need to add another column where there is information on whether the two individuals in the Dyad ate the same thing or not (or unknown, if the other dyad member doesn't have any data) **within a single Scan** (and this is what is most important).

The aim would be for my data to look like this:

| Individual | Scan | Food.Consumed | Dyad.ID | Same.Food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Raisins | 1 | No |
| Aa | 1 | Melon | 1 | No |
| B | 1 | Raisins | 2 | No |
| Cc | 1 | Melon | 3 |  |
| Bb | 1 | Peach | 2 | No |
| Ee | 1 | Melon | 5 | Yes |
| E | 1 | Melon | 5 | Yes |
| F | 1 | Peach | 6 |  |
| Aa | 2 | Melon | 5 | Yes |
| C | 2 | Peach | 5 |  |
| A | 2 | Melon | 6 | Yes |

I haven't managed to find anything which would allow me to look at same strings within cells of a specific column (here = Food.Consumed) and rows (of the same Dyad ID number), while restricting the search to only within each scan every time (and repeating this for each following scan).

Hopefully this is all clear, thank you for the help!

Comment: Corrected! Thank you for spotting this!

Comment: Also, in the expected output, for the last three rows, should that be `"No", "No", ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Scan, Dyad.ID) %>%
   mutate(Same.Food = case_when(n() == 1 ~ "", 
        n_distinct(Food.Consumed) == 1 & n() == 2 ~ "Yes",
       TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I apply the command, I get this error message:

''Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.'' which is strange because 'case_when' is a dplyr verb.. 
I've made sure to load the library before and I've tried using `dplyr::case_when` but nothing is working..

Comment: @Juliette it is working for me though.  Can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')`.  I used `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.8’`

Comment: my console says `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.8’`. I am using a Mac, could the problem be due to this?

Comment: @Juliette I am also using `Mac`.  So, it is not an issue.  Can you try this on a fresh R session with only `library(dplyr)` loaded

Comment: @Juliette Please let me know if restarting helped or not. thanks

Comment: It took me a while but everything works now after restarting R! Thank you so much for your help!!